# Copying files to Remote Location using Ant Builder

Tags: java, ant, build

Please help to find why I couldn't copy a jar file to ftp location.It takes C: as remote location root.Please help correct erroneous.

**build.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="D:/build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="D:/build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="D:/build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="D:/build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="D:/build/jar/ffjar.jar" basedir="D:/build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.ant.Test"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>   

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="D:/build/jar/ffjar.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>


    <target name="deploy">      
        <ftp server="ip"
           remotedir="/home/ecnet"
           userid="user"
           password="pass"
           depends="yes">
           <fileset dir="/home/ecnet/ffjar.jar"/>
        </ftp>
      </target>

</project>
```

**Output :**

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Joseph.M\WorkPlace_Struts2\CheckAnt\build.xml
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\build
compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\Joseph.M\WorkPlace_Struts2\CheckAnt\build.xml:11: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\build\classes
jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\build\jar
      [jar] Building jar: D:\build\jar\ffjar.jar
run:
     [java] Hello Ant World
deploy:
      [ftp] sending files

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Joseph.M\WorkPlace_Struts2\CheckAnt\build.xml:34: C:\home\ecnet\ffjar.jar does not exist.

Total time: 7 seconds
```

Comment: The error message says "C:\home\ecnet\ffjar.jar does not exist". Your _jar_ target builds the destination file "D:/build/jar/ffjar.jar". Seems to be a bit different ...

Comment: Thanks for reply.What you mean by "different"?.That's strange thing I don't know.How Ant takes root as C.

Comment: Different means: They are not equal! And it is clear why it is so. Your _ftp_ task tells to take the file "/home/ecnet/ffjar.jar". As you are running it from drive "C:", this is appended. Voilà.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with this line

```
<fileset dir="/home/ecnet/ffjar.jar"/>
```

As i believe your Ant is installed in C: drive so it is trying to resolve this path accordingly. You need to change this path to actual path like:

```
<fileset dir="D:/build/jar/ffjar.jar"/>
```

I would suggest creating a properties file and define all paths there and use variables instead of hard-coding all the paths in `build.xml`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Am building jar in local and copying to the Remote Location 10.151.*.*@user:pass  /home/ecnet-- this is location.but you have mentioned to D:.Please tell me why.

Comment: Problem because I didn't understand fileset tag of build.xml

Comment: That is the location you have specified under `remotedir="/home/ecnet"` the fileset tag will pic files from your local drive and ftp will push them to remotedir